# #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'potentialclients'

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am making a database and I have been trying to get this done for a good amount of time.

```
SELECT clients.nombre, clients.zona 
FROM developmentrequest,potentialclients, users
INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id_clients = developmentrequest.id_clients
INNER JOIN users ON clients.id_user = users.id
WHERE users.id =4 AND developmentrequest.id_states=3

UNION

SELECT potentialclients.nombre, potentialclients.zona
FROM developmentrequest,potentialclients, users
INNER JOIN potentialclients ON potentialclients.id_potentialclients = developmentrequest.id_potentialclients
INNER JOIN users ON potentialclients.id_user = users.id
WHERE users.id =4 AND developmentrequest.id_states=3
```

this is the code I have been working on and it gives the problem: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'potentialclients', now I have tried naming potentialclients with an alias like pc1 but it starts giving other errors with other columns, I dont know what to do :C

Comment: Avoid mixing comma-separated tables and the `JOIN` clause in the same query.

Comment: Avoid using comma-separated tables at all and use `JOIN` clauses exclusively.

Comment: For a self-join you **must** use table aliases.  Your `FROM developmentrequest,potentialclients, users` constitutes an implicit `INNER JOIN` of the three tables.

Comment: Mixing [explicit and implicit joins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44917/1422451), you are joining some tables *twice* in each `SELECT` statement without aliasing to distinguish between duplicate pairs.